# Soap Web service with portable class library

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, portable-class-library

I've a portable class library and I need to consume soap web service within it-I'm using .NET Framework 4.5 and visual studio 2012-.. I added a service reference to it and I'm using it by creating a client and using event handler to use it's operations. But it returns this exception:

```
The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.
```

I've noticed that client configuration file is empty.I wanted to know how t consume this service

Comment: Are you missing the System.ServiceModel.Client configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to capture request - response pair and start working from there. First thing you want to see is actual response and not .NET message, check what [status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) is returned. That should be enough to get you on the right track.